# Installing CassandraInterpreter on Zeppelin

Tags: scala, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, apache-zeppelin, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to install CassandraInterpreter on Zeppelin. As in documention is said I did:

```
bin/install-interpreter.sh --name cassandra
```

Which made cassandra folder with all dependecies. I have some concerns now. I'm using ***open-source cassandra 3.10.*** and Zeppelin version ***0.7.0***. 
As I saw by dependecies Zeppelin is downloading *cassandra-deriver* of **datastax** and I'm not using Datastaxs Cassandra.

Furthermore, I added Cassandra as Intepreter and made my first script:

```
%cassandra
HELP;
```

And something ugly happend:

```
INFO [2017-06-01 12:50:42,695] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1496314241621 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.CassandraInterpreter116220$
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:54:01,128] ({pool-1-thread-2} InterpreterGroup.java[close]:156) - Close interpreter group 2CJDRW3SU:shared_process
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:10,327] ({Thread-0} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[run]:95) - Starting remote interpreter server on port 39611
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:10,836] ({pool-1-thread-2} RemoteInterpreterServer.java[createInterpreter]:190) - Instantiate interpreter org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.CassandraInterpreter
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:10,930] ({pool-2-thread-2} SchedulerFactory.java[jobStarted]:131) - Job remoteInterpretJob_1496314750927 started by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.CassandraInterpreter15405091$
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:10,936] ({pool-2-thread-2} CassandraInterpreter.java[open]:164) - Bootstrapping Cassandra Java Driver to connect to 10.60.213.61,on port 9042
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,281] ({pool-2-thread-2} NettyUtil.java[<clinit>]:83) - Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,880] ({pool-2-thread-2} DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.java[init]:95) - Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct d$
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,882] ({pool-2-thread-2} Cluster.java[init]:1485) - New Cassandra host /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 added
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,883] ({pool-2-thread-2} Cluster.java[init]:1485) - New Cassandra host /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 added
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,883] ({pool-2-thread-2} Cluster.java[init]:1485) - New Cassandra host /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 added
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,883] ({pool-2-thread-2} Cluster.java[init]:1485) - New Cassandra host /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 added
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,883] ({pool-2-thread-2} Cluster.java[init]:1485) - New Cassandra host /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 added
 INFO [2017-06-01 12:59:11,884] ({pool-2-thread-2} Cluster.java[init]:1485) - New Cassandra host /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 added
ERROR [2017-06-01 12:59:11,991] ({pool-2-thread-2} Job.java[run]:188) - Job failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at org.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine.<init>(TemplateEngine.scala:170)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$.<init>(DisplaySystem.scala:37)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$.<clinit>(DisplaySystem.scala)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$.<init>(DisplaySystem.scala:369)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.DisplaySystem$NoResultDisplay$.<clinit>(DisplaySystem.scala)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.EnhancedSession.<init>(EnhancedSession.scala:40)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.InterpreterLogic.<init>(InterpreterLogic.scala:98)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.cassandra.CassandraInterpreter.open(CassandraInterpreter.java:189)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:69)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:482)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
        at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

As I see, its problem in Scala version which is by default I mean *2.10.5* and Zeppelin is downloading the same. I tried so swap whole scala with *2.12.0* and I got error about  ***Display...*** also scala error. Any ideas?

I'm suspecting on missmatch of Cassandra drivers since I have open-source Cassandra and driver is for Datastax and I cannot find the one for open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to install cassandra driver, you need to change little bit interpreter jars. 
In order to this, after you installed cassandra via zeppelin interpreter you need to go in your

`ZEPPELIN_HOME/zeppelin-server/interpreter/cassandra`

Afterwards you need this libs ->

```
cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1.jar   netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar            
scalate-core_2.11-1.7.1.jar      commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar          
netty-handler-4.0.33.Final.jar    scalate-util_2.11-1.7.1.jar
guava-16.0.1.jar                 
netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar         
scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar
lz4-1.3.0.jar                    
scala-compiler-2.11.2.jar               
slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
metrics-core-3.1.2.jar          
scala-library-2.11.2.jar                 
snappy-java-1.0.5.4.jar
netty-buffer-4.0.33.Final.jar    
scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar  
zeppelin-cassandra_2.11-0.7.2.jar
netty-codec-4.0.33.Final.jar     
scala-reflect-2.11.2.jar
```

It will work fine when after this change, just restart interpreter.